# watermark image using php imagick get gray background

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I create an image for watermark
[watermark.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXNkf.png)

using this code

```
$im   = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$text = 'watermark text';
$draw->setFontFamily('Arial');
$draw->setFontSize(50);
$draw->setFillColor('white');
$draw->setStrokeColor('black');
$draw->setStrokeWidth(1);
$draw->setStrokeAntialias(true);
$draw->setTextAntialias(true);
$qfm = $im->queryFontMetrics($draw, $text);
$im->newImage($qfm['textWidth'], $qfm['textHeight'], new ImagickPixel('rgba(120,120,120,0)'));
$im->setImageFormat('png');
$text_x = 1;
$text_y = ceil($qfm['textHeight'] / 2) + ceil($qfm['ascender'] / 3) - 1;
$im->annotateImage($draw, $text_x, $text_y, 0, $text);
$im->writeImage('watermark.png');
```

then later, I use it to watermark an image using this code

```
$wmark = new imagick('watermark.png');
$image = new imagick('image.jpg');
$wmark_width  = $wmark->getImageWidth();
$wmark_height = $wmark->getImageHeight();
$image_width  = $image->getImageWidth();
$image_height = $image->getImageHeight();
$wmark->setImageOpacity(0.3);
$wmark_x = floor(($image_width - $wmark_width) / 2);
$wmark_y = floor(($image_height - $wmark_height) / 2);
$image->compositeImage($wmark, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, $wmark_x, $wmark_y);
$image->writeImage('result.jpg');
```

somehow it doesn't keep the transparent background and revert to gray instead and the text have some weird stroke too
[result.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DtzOy.jpg)

why is that? how can I just add the watermark to the image without anything change?

ImageMagick 6.9.11-60 Q16 x86_64 2021-01-25

PHP 7.4.33

Comment: JPEG does not support transparency.  Make your output PNG if you want to save transparency.

Comment: I did try `$image->setImageFormat('png');` then save it as a png file, the result still the same

Comment: After the composite, before writing your output, try adding https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.setimagecolorspace.php to imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB (int). See example for how to set it at the link.

Comment: I did try `$image->setImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);` or `$image->transformImageColorspace(Imagick::COLORSPACE_SRGB);`  the result still the same

Comment: Where did you put that?  Try just before and also try just after the composite.  Post the background image also.

Comment: I try before the composite before and then try after the composite still the same

Comment: Try https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.transformimagecolorspace.php